# Find the 3rd & 4th digits from a number

Tags: python

Like if we have an integer

```
a = 1234
b = a % 10 #extracts the final digit 4
```

What about If I wanna extract the 2nd to last digit 3? Similarly for 1 & 2

Answer (score 4):

Convert to string and use indexing:

```
a_as_str = str(a)
print(a[your index])
```

If again needed as integer, convert it back:

```
c = int(a[0])
```

Comment: Converting to a `str` when computers work way better with numbers than with `str` (at the end a `str` is an array of bytes that each represent a character) seems contraproductive to me for such an easy operation.

Comment: @Adirio I admit this is not the most efficient solution, but it's easily understandable for humans. And they have to deal with the code, not computers.

Comment: I get your point, but in an easy operation as this (dividing by 10 as many times as needed to shift the digit you want to the units position) a comment should be enough to remember your future you what that meant.

Comment: @Adirio That's probably true for a language like C, but in Python, every `int` is an object and every operator a method call, which makes your calculation not so trivial as it seems.

Answer (score 3):

First use integer division to set it in the first position:

```py
a = 1234
n = 3
b = ( a // 10**(n-1) ) % 10  # 2
```

`n` is the position you want to retrieve.

```
n = 1 --> 10^0 = 1    --> 1234 // 1 = 1234 --> b = 1234 % 10 = 4
n = 2 --> 10^1 = 10   --> 1234 // 10 = 123 --> b = 123  % 10 = 3
n = 3 --> 10^2 = 100  --> 1234 // 100 = 12 --> b = 12   % 10 = 2
n = 4 --> 10^3 = 1000 --> 1234 // 1000 = 1 --> b = 1    % 10 = 1
```